# Python programming - beginner

Tags: python

so i have to create a code in which it reads every third letter and it creates a space in between each letter, my code creates the spaces but it also has a space after the last letter, this is my code:

```
msg = input("Message? ")
length = len(msg)
for i in range (0, length, 3):
 x = msg[i]
 print(x, end=" ")
```

My output was:

> Message?

I enter:

```
 cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
```

I get back

```
c h a l l e n g e
```

when the output isn't meant to have the last " " after the e.

I have read by adding `print(" ".join(x))` should give me the output i need but when i put it in it just gives me a error. Please and Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the second version that used `join` but failed? `join` requires a list or sequence and you likely didn't build the list first.

Comment: Use the title to describe the specific problem. The current title has little information.

Answer (score 7):

In Python, strings are one kind of data structures called sequences. Sequences support slicing, which is a simple and fancy way of doing things like "from nth", "to nth" and "every nth". The syntax is `sequence[from_index:to_index:stride]`. One does not even a `for` loop for doing that.ago

We can get every 3th character easily by omitting `from_index` and `to_index`, and have stride of 3:

```
>>> msg = input("Message? ")
cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
>>> every_3th = msg[::3]
>>> every_3th
'challenge'
```

Now, we just need to insert spaces after each letter. `separator.join(iterable)` will join elements from `iterable` together in order with the given `separator` in between. A string is an iterable, whose elements are the individiual characters.

Thus we can do:

```
>>> answer = ' '.join(every_3th)
>>> answer
'c h a l l e n g e'
```

For the final code we can omit intermediate variables and have still a quite readable two-liner:

```
>>> msg = input('Message? ')
>>> print(' '.join(msg[::3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
>>> print " ".join([msg[i] for i in range(0, len(msg), 3)])
'c h a l l e n g e'
```